# Home automation using a Cloud Platform

Tags: c#, .net, azure, cloud, x10

I'm trying to make a prototype of my next application, and before I can start, I wanted to know your feedback about it.

The user will be able to control his home remotely using a mobile phone.

First, the mobile phone will send a request to the cloud plateforme wich is going to do some authentifications (username, ip-address, password) and send the user request to his office laptop (home storing a Web Service WCF) and this one will ask the CM15 to do the rest of the job (switch on/off a light, ...)

And just wanted to know if this thing seems correct to you.

[image: HomeAutomation]

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify if you are using a polling or push model for cloud to home communications.

Polling is easier, and would handle home network disconnection better but you could also use Azure Service Bus to provide a way to call down from the cloud to the laptop as well.